# Converting a java web start application (jnlp) to an applet

Tags: java, applet, jnlp

I have a java application which is a java web start application. It is used to administer a remote server. Now I want to convert it to an applet to run in the browser. Is there an easy way to achieve this. What are my options to achieve this? By the way my java application stores and reads some conf files on the client file system. Would this be a problem if I run my application as an applet?

Comment: *"Is there an easy way to achieve this."*  Nope.  Applets are a PITA.  For 'easy' I typically recommend people convert their applets into free-floating apps. launched using ..JWS.

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be too hard since Sun/Oracle introduced [JNLP](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html) support for applets in version 6u10 (1.6.0_10).
In short:

1. Adapt your app to the applet [lifecycle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/lifeCycle.html),
2. set the [permissions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/step2.html) correctly and
3. [sign](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/keytool.html) it with an [official certificate](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/java-code-signing-1915323.html).
4. (and of course [embedd](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/embeddingJNLPFileInWebPage.html) your applet in a web page)

Comment: What benefit do I gain from signing with an official certificate?

Comment: You can run your applet in web browsers without any changes. Otherwise your applet will not be able to run. (You have to add your selfsigned certificate to the java trust store or change the security slider to medium)

Comment: So in an enterprise environment where rolling out a modified java trust store are no problem there are no real benefit? Will that stupid security question disappear if I do this?

Comment: If you are in an enterprise environment and just add your certficiate to the java truststore (which is a different one than the windows or browser (e.g. firefosx) truststore, then yes.